# Displaying a pymongo cursor without loading in a list

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.8, pymongo-3.x

I am working on a PyQT5 app. I want to display a large dataset extracted from a MongoDB database.

To do so, I extract my collection in 3 cursors (I need to sort the display). However, until now, I was casting the cursors in a list, then emitting it.

But now my database grew significantly in size, and runtime became a major issue. Going through lists is time-consuming. Therefore, I am trying to find a way to directly access the cursor in its entirety without looping through all of it (I know it sounds a bit tricky since the cursor is just a reference to the collection)

An example of what is done now :

```
D1 = list(self.collection.find({"$and":[ {"location": current_location}, {"vehicle":"Car"  }]}))

D2 = list(self.collection.find({"$and":[ {"location": current_location}, {"vehicle":{"$nin":["Car","Truck"]}}]}))
    
D3 = list(self.collection.find({"$and":[ {"location": current_location}, {"vehicle" : "Truck"}]}).sort([("_id",-1)]).limit(60 - len(D1)))

extracted = D1 + D2 + D3
l_data_extracted.emit(extracted) # send the loaded data to the front
```

Loading 3 cursors are time-consuming, but then passing them in 1 list makes it heavier for the app.

I looked for resources about cursor management, but every time, I see answers which involve looping or casting (which I already do).

Would there be a way to directly emit the cursor and a bit like in C, pass the argument by reference to get the pointed data ? Or am I bound to loop/cast in the list due to its particular nature?

Comment: I've never used mongo, so I'm not sure I'm really understanding the problem here. Also, your code is too short to actually understand where the problem resides (I suggest you to provide a [mre]): are you going to cycle through *all* elements of the merged list? If `self.collection.find()` returns a cursor, can't you just emit those cursors, instead of converting them to a list, and then just cycle to their contents?

Comment: The snippet I've shared is what I currently do (converting in lists). But I was wondering if I could skip this step. If I set a Cursor as an argument in emit(), I get a TypeError because of the Cursor type. I looked for an alternative without much success

Comment: A cursor is not a list, if you're creating a custom signal using a `list` signature, you'll get a TypeError for that, so you need it to change to `object` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing it to an 'object' "? Like a simple datatype (e.g: list or dict) or do you mean something else?
I know I can't use the Cursor like this, I was wondering if there was a swifter (and nicer) way to process it and display the information on my UI.

Comment: I didn't write "changing it to *an* object", I specifically wrote "change to `object`": `l_data_extracted = pyqtSignal(object)`.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry for the misreadings.
Okok thank you, I will check what I can do with this.